# Should I add a M.2 SSD or upgrade 2.5" SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 - i7559 gaming laptop. Currently, I have only a 240G 2.5" SSD SATA III 6Gbps. I am running outside of storage space with 240G. I am looking to add more storage space.

I currently have a M.2 SSD slot, but it is empty. I did some research and found out that M.2 SSD is faster than the traditional 2.5", but more expensive. Since, I am new to computer hardware. I am wondering if it is better to buy a bigger 2.5" SSD or to add a new M.2 SSD?

I do care about the stuffs I already have in the old 240G 2.5" SSD, so I do have to transfer my data to the new 2.5" SSD. Is it complicated to do so? If it is, I can think that it would be inconvenient. Whereas if I add a new M.2 SSD, I do not need to do any data transfer, right? I listed some pros and cons I came up:

```
Change to a bigger 2.5" SSD:
PROS:
  - Cheaper for bigger storage

Cons:
  - Have to transfer the data over

Add a new M.2 SSD:
Pros:
  - Faster
  - transfer is easier?
Cons:
  - cost more
```

Please let me know what you guys think and what are your recommendations.

Comment: To be honest.. the best any of us can do is to work off of the same information you have already gathered. I myself already know these things but would have the same dilemma as you. NICE WORK.  Some people would opt for easier while others would opt for optimal performance.  It isn't HARD to transfer your OS.. but it is work.. IMHO the performance diff is mostly unnoticeable.  I myself would probably ADD the m.2 drive to the existing AS SPACE.  If I ever need to reinstall, I would probably switch the primary drive to m.2 then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did some research and found out that M.2 SSD is faster than the traditional 2.5", but more expensive.

M.2 **actually is a connector type**. In contract to many other connectors, it can incorporate several buses: PCI Express, Serial ATA, and USB (whereas most connectors provide only one bus, for example, SATA plug provides only SATA).

**Thus it is very important to check, what buses are provided by the motherboard/chipset on M.2 connector**. Some motherboards provide only SATA, some only PCI Express, and some do both.

M.2 **PCI Express** drives (also known as NVMe drives) are often much faster than their SATA counterparts (and more expensive though).
However, M.2 **SATA** drives are almost no different from their 2.5" counterparts (in terms of performance and price), except for the altered form-factor (drive performance depends on its bus, controller and memory chips, and in this case is limited by the SATA bus).

In your case, it seems that your laptop's motherboard exposes only SATA bus to the M.2 connector. So, if you're planning an upgrade, you should look only for M.2 SATA drives, which usually do not significantly differ in prices with "classic" 2.5" SSD drives.

---

As for your case, you have two options:

- Add another M.2 SSD as a "data" drive. Leave everything on your current drive (including OS)
- Purchase both M.2 SSD (for OS and "hot" data) and a large 2.5 HDD or SSD<sup>[1]</sup> (for storing "cold" data).

---

<sup>[1] As of 2020, there are some QLC SSDs that provide cheap and large storage space. Their significant disadvantage is their write performance on larger volumes of data, so they are mostly used as WORM (write once, read many) storage - which is ideal for storing cold data such as photos, archives etc.</sup>

Comment: Hi, sorry that it has been a while. How do I know what data type my SSD M.2 connector supports?

Comment: @IsaakNewton you should check specifications for your laptop. There is this forum thread: https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/How-do-I-know-if-Dell-inspiron-7559-supports-either-M-2-NVMe-or/td-p/6033220 , it says that your laptop supports SATA-based M.2 drives only.

Comment: Ok, I typed `wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\storage path msft_disk get Model,BusType` in my command prompt, it says that my M.2 is type 11, which is SATA

Comment: Is really a M.2 SATA no different than a 2.5" SATA in terms of speed and performance?

Comment: @IsaakNewton they both use the same SATA 6 Gbit/s bus. There may be differences between models due to different memory chips/controllers used, but in general they both are in "500MBps league", and not in 2-3GBps one, as most NVMe models do